# Rewrite Rule - What Exactly Do They Mean

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using a `htaccess` file to rewrite all of my pages, and everything is working completely fine, except that I have to admit to not knowing exactly what certain parts mean.  For example, what do the following lines mean and do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Also, can you clear up the meaning of the letters in `[NC,L,QSA]` as well as `([\w-]+)`. Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This line tells server to stop rewriting if the request was already for an existing file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This line tells server to stop rewriting if the request was already for an existing directory.

```
[NC,L,QSA]
```

These are the Rewrite flags,

NC=> No Case, makes the rewrite pattern case-insentive,
L=> means Last, it tells server to stop proccessing other rewrite rules,if the rule has matched its pattern.

QSA=> Query string append ,appends query strings to new target url.

Source :

Apache mod_rewrite =>
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Flags =>
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Thank you Starkeen, that's extremely helpful.  What about the `([\w-]+)` part? I get the one for numbers being `([0-9]+)`, but why is this just a `w`?

Comment: ([\w-]+) matchs numbers ,letters and hypen one or more times ,like ([A-Za-z0-9-],

Comment: Ah. Thank you so much for clearing that all up for me. Very helpful to know just what these things mean and do :-)

Comment: @FootBlogger you are very much welcome. Glad I could help,cheers.